# Wifi connection frequently dropping in hotspots and university campus, home Wifi works fine

Tags: wireless

For some reason, my Wifi connection frequently drops everywhere except at home. I didn't have this problem with Windows 7 so I guess it's not a hardware problem. My best guess so far is that my connection timeout is very low so if my connection isn't able to reach the router after a few second, the connection drops. Is that likely to be the problem? If so, how could I fix this? Otherwise, what would be an alternative cause for this strange behavior?

Update: I just noticed my home connection is WEP whereas my university connection is WPA.

Comment: What type of authentication does this wireless use? Do you've occasional problems in authentication? Please note that I'm not knowledgeable enough to solve your problem, but the things I've asked can help someone to do it.

Comment: You should be able to add some more information to your question by finding the relevant information from /var/log/messages, /var/log/debug and /var/log/dmesg. One thing you may want to grep for is "500ms" - I am having a similar problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29316/steps-to-diagnose-snu5600-disconnection-problem

Answer (score 3):

First try:

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```

This often works if you have an N standard compatible WiFi card.

There are three others solutions that might help:

1. Update the kernel.
2. Change networkmanager to WICD. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD
3. Use ndiswrapper instead of the linux driver. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Answer (score 0):

Same OS version and situation here. My luck is intermittent. It's something to do with MSCHAPv2/PEAP requirements. Things dramatically improved for me with a few things. This may not be a definitive list, but hopefully will help get things moving...

(1) **[wicd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD)**

> WICD (pronounced like wicked) is an open source wired and wireless network manager for Linux which aims to provide a simple interface to connect to networks with a wide variety of settings. It provides support only for wired and wireless networks (no fancy VPNs, DSL routing and such), but it's a good alternative if NetworkManager gives you problems.

(2) **Get your campus' certificate**

Contact anyone in your IT help desk that has any clue about linux. I finally did -- after submitting a few helpdesk tickets with the words ubuntu and linux clearly stated. Someone finally responded with the magic words: "Oh, grab this certificate."

[image]
Also in my settings