# Change from the minstrel algorithm

Tags: wireless, modprobe

I would like to stop my network card from using the Minstrel algorithm because of [a problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29316/steps-to-diagnose-snu5600-disconnection-problem) I am having.

I have tried creating /etc/modprobe.d/80211.conf with the following in it:

```
options mac80211
ieee80211_default_rc_algo=pid
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the whole thing on one line:

```
options mac80211 ieee80211_default_rc_algo=pid
```

And then reboot.

Confirm the parameter has taken effect:

```
cat /sys/module/mac80211/parameters/ieee80211_default_rc_algo
```